# unir sentencia CASE con SELECT

Tags: php, sql, subconsultas

Necesito realizat una consulta en donde devuelva el codigo de material(sin repetirse), nombre, unidad de medida, cantidad en entrada de ese material y la cantidad de salidas, y una cantidad total
esto es lo que e intentado

```
SELECT `movimientos`.`codigo_material`, `material`.`nombre_material`, `unidad_medida`.`unidad`, (SELECT Count(tipo_movimiento) FROM movimientos WHERE tipo_movimiento='ENTRADA' and m.codigo_material=codigo_material) As ENTRADA, 
(SELECT Count(tipo_movimiento) FROM movimientos WHERE tipo_movimiento='SALIDA' and m.codigo_material=codigo_material) As SALIDA,, `movimientos`.`cantidad`, `material`.`cantidad`
FROM `movimientos` 
    INNER JOIN `material` ON `movimientos`.`codigo_material` = `material`.`codigo` 
    INNER JOIN `unidad_medida` ON `material`.`unidad` = `unidad_medida`.`idunidad_medida`
```

Por separado si funciona: aqui suma la cantidad cuando el tipo de movimiento es ENTRADA o salida.

```
SELECT  m.codigo_material,
(SELECT SUM(cantidad) FROM movimientos WHERE tipo_movimiento='ENTRADA' and m.codigo_material=codigo_material) As ENTRADA, 
(SELECT SUM(cantidad) FROM movimientos WHERE tipo_movimiento='SALIDA' and m.codigo_material=codigo_material) As SALIDA
FROM movimientos m  
ORDER BY `m`.`codigo_material` ASC
```

y aqui hace la union entre la tabla llamada material y moviminetos

```
SELECT `movimientos`.`codigo_material`, `material`.`nombre_material`, `unidad_medida`.`unidad`, `movimientos`.`tipo_movimiento`, `movimientos`.`tipo_movimiento`, `movimientos`.`saldo`, `material`.`cantidad`
FROM `movimientos` 
    LEFT JOIN `material` ON `movimientos`.`codigo_material` = `material`.`codigo` 
    LEFT JOIN `unidad_medida` ON `material`.`unidad` = `unidad_medida`.`idunidad_medida`
```

base de datos:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/38PrfMVrWrHXJUDGq3bdxm/9

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas hacer una subconsulta. Solo es necesario tener una expresión CASE dentro de la función de agregado. No incluyo la unidad de medida porque no está dentro de los datos de muestra que incluiste, pero solo hace falta agregar la tabla y columna a la consulta.

```
SELECT mov.codigo_material,
       mat.nombre_material, 
       SUM( CASE WHEN mov.tipo_movimiento='ENTRADA' THEN mov.cantidad ELSE 0 END) As ENTRADA, 
       SUM( CASE WHEN mov.tipo_movimiento='SALIDA'  THEN mov.cantidad ELSE 0 END) As SALIDA,
       SUM( CASE WHEN mov.tipo_movimiento='ENTRADA' 
                   OR mov.tipo_movimiento='SALIDA'  THEN mov.cantidad ELSE 0 END) As TOTAL
FROM movimientos mov
INNER JOIN material mat ON mov.codigo_material = mat.codigo
GROUP BY mov.codigo_material,
       mat.nombre_material;
```

Comment: y para añadir la unidad de medida si seria por medio de sub consulta?

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/38PrfMVrWrHXJUDGq3bdxm/10

Comment: No, es por medio de un JOIN, así como la tabla de material.